# Why can't I browse the internet with Safari, but Chrome is working?

Tags: macos, safari, mac-appstore, internet, proxy

I can't browse to any website using Safari; yet, Google Chrome and Firefox are working fine. The Mac App Store also reports that it cannot connect.

I am running OSX 10.7.2 on a 2011 MacBook Pro.

Comment: have you tried Firefox too? at least to have a third opinion and see if your WebKit (overridden by Chrome) is having a problem.

Comment: Firefox also works. Also just checked and it looks like iTunes is unable to connect also.

Comment: Do you have anything in your Proxies? (Safari -> Preferences -> Advanced -> Proxies (Change Settings).?

Comment: Autodiscover was ticked. I unticked and voila! Newish to this site but do you want to post the solution so i can flag as the as the answer? Thank you

Comment: done, glad to hear you fixed it.

Comment: Similar: [Safari does not load any site but there is Internet connection](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/131505/22781).

Comment: Make sure that firewall (such as _LittleSnitch_) is not blocking any outgoing connections.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As we have found the solution using Comments, here's the formal response.

Whenever you experience issues with Safari, App Store, iTunes and any other service that uses the "same" WebKit, but seem to see no problem in Google Chrome or Firefox, it's good to check if you have your Proxies configuration clear. Since sometimes Chrome (and Firefox) override these settings (for their own multi platform stuff), they may work while the formers fail.

This is easily checked by opening Safari -> Preferences -> Advanced -> Proxies (Change Settings).

Make sure Autodiscover is not checked. It should probably look all empty like this:

[image]

**note/off-topic**: the Use PASV FTP is usually a good idea if you are behind a router/modem/NAT like Airport Extreme or AirportExpress (or any other to be honest), since FTP was not designed to be used behind these "hacks". In any case, if you don't know what it is, you can safely ignore it, but if you have FTP problems every now and then (or FTP is slow as hell), check that and try again.

The local ignores for proxies was added by the Operating System, but it's usually a good idea to have your local stuff ignore the proxy. ;)

Comment: Thanks for that, Martin! My Chrome & FF & Opera all worked fine but my Safari says that my MB wasn't connected to the internet. Your tip got my Safari working again! I'da never guessed it, because that had always been checked before, in all my Mac OS's (currently, I'm running Yosemite).

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem. I'm running 10.12.2

Comment: Awesome.. worked Perfectly