# Why can I browse with Firefox but not with Safari or Chrome?

Tags: safari, google-chrome, web-browsing, firefox, http

I had a problem a while back where Chrome was working fine but Safari and Firefox were not. This was fixed by unchecking the "auto-discover proxy" box in the network configuration. See my previous question: [Why can't I browse the internet with Safari, but Chrome is working?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34824/why-cant-i-browse-the-internet-with-safari-but-chrome-is-working)

Today I find myself able to browse with Firefox but not with Chrome or Safari. A select few pages are still working but mostly nothing. Chrome will give me an error:

```
 Error 7 (net::ERR_TIMED_OUT): The operation timed out.
```

To help rule out a few things this even happens when trying to browse to my firewall http://192.168.0.1

Thanks for any help in advance!

I'm running OS X 10.7.2.

Comment: It seems like this is possibly only affecting sites which use SSL (unforunately this is most of the sites i frequent: gmail, facebook etc)

Comment: I found http://superuser.com/questions/349740/mac-os-x-lion-10-7-2-update-breaks-ssl but haven't had much luck with the suggestions although they seem to be headed in the right direction (i think a captive portal is responsible for breaking it!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't be 100% sure which of these resolved the issue but i took these steps and everything is now working (touch wood):

1. Terminal

   - sudo mv ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain.bak
   - sudo mv /Library/Keychains/System.keychain /Library/Keychains/System.keychain.bak
2. Reboot
3. I'd now lost network connectivity and wifi wouldn't connect- i think this is because the wireless key is stored in the keychain which i'd "deleted". I managed to resolve this by going to network preferences, wifi, assist-me and stepping through the wizard.
4. Lastly i ran software update and upgraded to 10.7.3

Voila