# Safari does not load any site but there is Internet connection

Tags: macos, safari, internet

A friend of mine asked me to help with his MacBook as Safari didn't load any site.

I connected to his computer using TeamViewer (so internet is basically working), and then did a ping on `Google.com`, which worked. His Mac runs on OSX 10.6.x (**Snow Leopard**) with Safari 5.x.

I've tried a few things including:

- PRAM reset
- Delete cookies and browser cache
- DNS flush
- Delete `cookies/cache/plist` in Library
- Delete and reinstall *Safari.app*

Non working. I tried downloading Firefox using `curl` but that seems also not to work.

Any idea what could be wrong?

edit:
No proxys active

Comment: Check his proxy?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by not loading - what does Safari and Firefox do?

Comment: @Mark firefox is currently not installed. safari does not load any page, it tries loading but after a few minutes it says unable to connect (does not matter if www.google.com or <ip of google.com>)

Comment: @Mathias711 ill check that when i am at home

Comment: @Zaiborg so the bit re Firefox is just saying curl does not work?

Comment: curl does not work, and sorftware update (deleted safari, installed from system dvd) says there are no updates available

Comment: Have you tried using Guest Account? Let's see if it's network misconfiguration, or Safari’s fault.

Comment: @sayzlim does that apply when you can ping a website but not open it in the browser?

Comment: @Zaiborg you mentioned that `curl` doesn’t work, but `ping` works. We’ll need to use a clean state Guest Account to see if we should troubleshooting at network level, or application level.

Comment: @sayzlim guest account does not do the thing. ping on google works, safari still not loading for example google.com

Comment: @Zaiborg don't put the answer as an edit add it as an answer yourself

Comment: don't safari and firefox both count on a framework of webkit?  could that have gone kablooey somehow?  when it fails how does it fail?  can you see page source from inside the browser, but it just doesn't render?

Comment: I have had a similar thing with a 10.6 machine. It turned out it  was the mDNSResponder being flaky. But took me a while to figure out because Chrome did work. (seems it uses it's own settings or something) doing a  `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder` to restart it fixed my issue. Interestingly Apple has a doc that gives a different command for 10.6   `sudo dscacheutil -flushcache` http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5343?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

Comment: Check the DNS server in network preferences for the network adapter you are trying to connect. Usually DNS server ip should be the same as the router ip address.

Answer (score 8):

I solved by making sure the network settings not picking any proxy options under Network > Advanced > Proxies.

Answer (score 4):

Is there any app such as Little Snitch that is installed?  If so, it could be blocking browsers but not Team Viewer and not Mail.

Answer (score 4):

1. Open a Finder window. From the Finder menu bar click *Go > Go to Folder*
2. Type or copy paste the following: `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db`.
3. Click Go then move the `Cache.db` file to the *Trash*.
4. Quit and relaunch Safari to test.

Answer (score 3):

I tried various options including the proxies  The only thing that solved it was
System Preferences > Network > Assist me > Connect to the internet
And it solved it on its own

Answer (score 0):

What about putting Firefox or Chrome on a USB stick and just copying it via Finder? If they also do not work, I would suspect something more generally wrong, not Safari itself. Might have to use portable version of those apps.

UPDATE: What about any recently installed firewall software? 
Anything that might have installed a webfilter or a webfilter appliance that might sit between your Mac and the gateway? 
Is NAC enabled on the network, preventing you from getting out until you hit a specific site for authorization?

Comment: installing firefox resulted in the same behaviour ...

Answer (score 0):

Check the DNS server in network preferences for the network adapter you are trying to connect. Usually DNS server ip should be the same as the router ip address.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue (internet on Safari and App Store app not working), and rebooting my computer ended up resolving the problem for me.